# Extracting specific value from json response

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I add a json value from a response to a variable and then print it this way `result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`, but what i want exactly is to get only one exact value from this json

here's the json

```
{
  "flags": [
    { "flagID": "0f0571b5-af7b-48e2-8418-044cbec0166d", "flagname": "lionsflag", "team": "lions", "membersnum": "4", "win": false },
    { "flags": "9819c0bd-e134-4950-a1ee-7f89450ee4b6", "flagname": "Barcaflag", "membersnum": "4", "win": true }
  ]
}
```

I only want to extract `lionsflag` string only from the first `flagname`, this value is able to change any time

Comment: like this: `flags.forEach((flag) => flag.flagname === "lionsflag" ? console.log(flag.flagname) : null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys and then check the related value is meet your demand or not

```js
let data = {
  "flags": [
    { "flagID": "0f0571b5-af7b-48e2-8418-044cbec0166d", "flagname": "lionsflag", "team": "lions", "membersnum": "4", "win": false },
    { "flags": "9819c0bd-e134-4950-a1ee-7f89450ee4b6", "flagname": "Barcaflag", "membersnum": "4", "win": true }
  ]
}

let value = "lionsflag"
data.flags.filter(d => Object.keys(d).forEach(e =>{
  if(d[e] == value){
   console.log(e + ";" + value)
  }
}))

let prop ='flagname'
console.log(data.flags[0][prop])
```

Comment: That's not what i want exactly, I only want to extract `lionsflag` string, and this value is able to change any time

Comment: I think you didn't understood what i want exactly, the value is able to change so maybe in the next request the value will be XXXXX and not lionsflag, so i want to extract this sting

Comment: @user7778555 so my original answer is meet your demand,you just need to make the filter value(in your case is lionsflag) to a variable,and using the variable to filter value

Comment: this solution doesn't work I also tried console.log(data.flags[0].flagname) in the browser console it works but in the code it doesn’t

Comment: @user7778555 do you mean you just want to filter by `flagname` but the value might change?

Comment: yes, i only want to get the value of `flagname` and add it to a variable as a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249036/discussion-between-lucumt-and-user7778555).